# React native video taking too much time to show video stream at beginning(nodejs streaming)

Tags: node.js, react-native, video-streaming, react-native-video

I am using nodejs video streaming on the backend and front-end side is React-native. The nodejs video streaming is works for me but its taking too much time to load at the beginning on video player and also not showing loading.
I'm using react-native-video component and I'm calling nodejs API for getting stream.

Comment: Please add some code to assist you on same !